# Representing UTF-8 in ASCII

Tags: c, utf-8, ascii

I am trying to code a lexer for language "go" in "C".But "go" used UTF-8 as it's character set and C used Ascii. So is it possible to represent the unicode characters in ascii?

Comment: Well, there is an encoding called [UTF-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7), but why shouldn't C be able to handle other non-ASCII encodings?

Comment: [Project ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) provides a portable implementation of Unicode handling for C as well as C++ and Java.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Erm, he'd need to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-7 for no apparent gain. In all these years, I have _never_ seen a use of UTF-7 outside of e-mails.

Comment: @DarkDust: Thanks, that's exactly why I was asking. While there is an ASCII representation of Unicode, it's unlikely he needs it to solve his problem...

Comment: You can't represent all unicode characters in ASCII because ASCII has only 128 characters. But you can use UTF-8 in C.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yeah, for most things he can indeed simply treat UTF-8 string as normal C strings. But things get messy when [comparing strings that have diacritic marks and other fun Unicode stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) :-)

Comment: I think you should take a look at libutf (either on plan9's website or on suckless.org): it's (imho) a lot simpler than ICU, it was written by (some of) the Go Authors, and iirc it's what they use in the go tools.

Answer (score 0):

C has a support for [multibyte strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte), but you have to mess with locales for it to work.

ASCII is actually a subset of UTF-8, so you can use standard C singlebyte string functions to some extent. Just remember that functions requiring or returning lengths are byte counts, not character counts.

For anything more sophisticated, you'll need external library.

Comment: You did mention it, but I'd also like to emphasize this: C multibyte string handling is locale sensitive!